# Multithreading Implementation for thread manager Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to read an excel sheet row wise with each row's specific cell containing URL's. I need to process those URL's by visiting the site programatically. Since serially visiting each cell in a single threaded model would be extremely slow, i am planning something like this:

```
Step-1: Read excel sheet's cell of nth row.
Step-2: nThreads++
Step-3: if nThreads==MAX_NO_OF_THREADS, sleep till one of the threads is finished.
        else Instantiate a thread to process the URL of that cell.
Step-4: Goto 1.
```

To implement this, I need the following things:

1-Some means to create a pool of threads. I can create using an array of thread objects.But would prefer better alternatives.

2-A Manager thread which does the task of fetching thread from pool,handling them the work and sleep till one thread is available to do the task.

So what options are available for me?

Comment: Use [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Don't try to create a pool on your own. Synchronization is tricky business.

Comment: @zapl cool! But what abt the manager thread responsible for delegating tasks and waiting?

Comment: This is a perfect task to be modeled by actors. Consider using somthing like Akka.

Comment: @raphw I would prefer standard J2SE utils instead of some third party libraries.

Comment: The largest architectural mistake to commit here is using synchronous I/O to fetch URLs. You *don't need* one thread per HTTP request. See `AsyncHttpClient`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik actually I am not dealing at such a low level with http requests. I am using HtmlUnit. So I need separate thread per url to make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to think of this as limiting the amount of concurrent tasks. This implies the use of runnables that need to be fed input and need to know when to stop running. Also you need to know when all tasks are finished to have an inidication of when all the work is done.

The simplest solution to this problem, I could come up with, is shown below.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Q21512025 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 
    try {
        new Q21512025(executor, 5).readCells();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdownNow();
}

private int maxTasks;
private ExecutorService executor;
private CountDownLatch finished;
private LinkedBlockingQueue<ExcellUrlCell> q;

public Q21512025(ExecutorService executor, int maxTasks) {
    this.executor = executor;
    this.maxTasks = maxTasks;
    finished = new CountDownLatch(maxTasks);
    q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ExcellUrlCell>();
}

public void readCells() throws Exception {

    for (int i = 0; i < maxTasks; i++) {
        executor.execute(new ExcellUrlParser(q, finished));
    }
    ExcellReader reader = new ExcellReader(getExampleUrls(10));
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        q.add(reader.next());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maxTasks; i++) {
        q.add(new ExcellUrlCell(null));
    }   
    System.out.println("Awaiting excell url cell tasks.");
    finished.await();
    System.out.println("Done.");
}

private URL[] getExampleUrls(int amount) throws Exception {

    URL[] urls = new URL[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        urls[i] = new URL("http://localhost:" + (i + 2000) + "/");
    }
    return urls;
}

static class ExcellUrlParser implements Runnable {

    private CountDownLatch finished;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ExcellUrlCell> q;

    public ExcellUrlParser(LinkedBlockingQueue<ExcellUrlCell> q, CountDownLatch finished) {
        this.finished = finished;
        this.q = q;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                ExcellUrlCell urlCell = q.take();
                if (urlCell.isFinished()) {
                    break;
                }
                processUrl(urlCell.getUrl());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            finished.countDown();
        }
    }

    private void processUrl(URL url) {
        try { Thread.sleep(1); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        System.out.println(url);
    }

}

static class ExcellReader implements Iterator<ExcellUrlCell> {

    private URL[] urls;
    private int index;

    public ExcellReader(URL[] urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (index < urls.length);
    }

    @Override
    public ExcellUrlCell next() {
        ExcellUrlCell urlCell = new ExcellUrlCell(urls[index]);
        index++;
        return urlCell;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}

static class ExcellUrlCell {

    private URL url;

    public ExcellUrlCell(URL url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public URL getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return (url == null);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a thread manager? I just happen to manage several Fork/Join servers on SourceForge.net You can break your request into separate components and run each component on a separate thread pool [see here for an introduction](http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/ForkJoinArticle.html) or you can dynamically decompose the request into identical tasks for execution on a pool of threads, [see here](http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/ConquerArticle.html)

Both these open-source products have been around for many years and can save you much effort.